# program stops execution after reception of a single character over UART

Tags: avr, uart

Why this simple program stops execution after reception of a single character over UART?
Normally the program blinks LED every half of second. When character is received the ISR should start. Nothing like this happens. The LED should blink once again but it doesn't. I am running it on atmega2560.

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

#include <stdint.h>

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#include <util/delay.h>

#define UART_BAUDRATE 9600
#define UART_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE 256

volatile uint8_t data = 'a';

ISR(USART0_RX_vect)
{
    // Receive character
    data = UDR0;
    
    // Blink LED
    PINB = 1 << PB7;
}

int main()
{
    // Configure LED
    DDRB = (1 << PB7);

    // Configure UART
    UBRR0 = F_CPU / 16 / UART_BAUDRATE - 1;
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXCIE0) | (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0);
    UCSR0A = 0;

    sei();

    while (1) {
        
        // Blink LED
        _delay_ms(500);
        PINB = 1 << PB7;

        // Transmit a character
        while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));
        UDR0 = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You must clear the interrupts flags before leaving the ISR. If you have multiple LEDs have it light each every step of the way at the beginning of the ISR, possibly throughout, and  just before exiting the ISR and just after leaving so you know exactly where it gets hung up.

Comment: Nope, it looks like the ISR is not even started. Adding cli() in any place of the ISR doesn't helps. Even moving LED blink one line above does nothing.

Comment: If it's never entering the ISR then that narrows down where to look , though I am not familiar with the particular ISR syntax you are using or that of the ATMEGA.  You also might need to enable interrupts elsewhere. I just know when I had trouble with the STM32, it was because the designated ISR function call name had to be in C and could not tolerate C++ name mangling so "extern" keyword was needed.

Comment: @DKNguyen The RX complete ISR flag is cleared by reading the data register, so that's not it. Perhaps the fuse bits are set wrong, is there a bootloader and to where the fuses point the vector table?

Comment: @Justme sounds like a good point. I'll test it.

Comment: You program does not even try to blink an LED, it only ever sets the pin to '1'.  Blinking would require alternating values.  Either you posted the wrong code, or any blinking you were seeing is because the program was crashing (or watchdog triggering) and restarting over and over again.

Comment: @ChrisStratton And this is what setting 1 in PIN does - it toggles the output. So it is correct. Code is not crashing. Was tested and after setting proper fuses works perfectly as I tested. If your watchdog is reseting the code means you have programmed the fuse enabling watchdog at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Justme comment it is also necessary to properly setup fuses informing that the interrupt vector table is located at lowest flash address. To do so the BOOTRST (Boot Reset vector Enabled) must be unprogrammed (1).

It can be achieved with AVRDUDE using following arguments:

```
-U lfuse:w:0xc2:m -U hfuse:w:0x99:m -U efuse:w:0xff:m
```

or in the source code by adding following instructions:

```
FUSES =
{
    .low = (FUSE_CKSEL0 & FUSE_CKSEL2 & FUSE_CKSEL3 & FUSE_SUT0),
    .high = (FUSE_BOOTSZ0 & FUSE_BOOTSZ1 & FUSE_SPIEN & FUSE_JTAGEN),
    .extended = EFUSE_DEFAULT,
};
```